How to Prevent Gradle Breaks Across Unity Versions?
I created a SDK for game developers, and I continue facing issues with Unity changing Gradle and other configuration settings with each Unity version release; version 2020 is different than 2021 and 2022 and so forth.
The problem is that my SDK works perfectly on Unity 2020.3.48f, however all versions after that there are errors and lint warnings. This is due to the changes.
Here is 2021 Project Settings

Here is 2022 Project Settings

How can I maintain backwards and forward compatibility? For example, can I create something like if the Unity version is 2022 or higher then different sets of DLL will be imported and if lower another set of DLL will be imported?
Anyone who has created SDKs to help game developers I would love to hear how you are handling this.
